# C - Add space inside brackets

Tags: c, arrays, string

So I am doing something wrong with this program and would like someones help. I want to add spaces between the brackets and the words inside. For instance if the original string is `if (x=5)` then I want to make it `if ( x=5 )`. Simple task I know and here is the code I have:

```
char* addSpaces(char* line) {

    int i,j;
    char *result = line;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i<strlen(line); i++,j++)          
    {
        if (line[i] == '[') {
            result[j] = line[i];
            j++;
            result[j] = ' ';
        }  
        else if (line[i] == ']') {
            result[j] = ' ';
            j++;
            result[j] = line[i];
        }                 
        else result[j] = line[i];                                        
    }

    result[j] = 0;

    return result;

}
```

For some reason it freezes when I run the program. I don't get any errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm can't work if the input and output strings point to the same buffer (which is how you have it set up). Since you're overwriting the input string with a longer string (at least in your example case), you end up overwriting the null terminator. That causes undefined behaviour the next time your loop condition calls `strlen`, and then all bets are off.

Instead of overwriting the input buffer, allocate a new larger buffer, do the copy, and then return a pointer to that new buffer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no validation of input buffer, or do you just assume that input buffer is long enough to hold after spaces are added? Like Carl said, it's better to allocate memory inside the function (you may need to run through your string once to calculate how much you need to allocate) and then return the newly allocated buffer that is filled with new value.